# Proper way to change a SVG <text> without changing its children <tspan>

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Consider this simple SVG with a `<text>` element containing some `<tspan>`s:

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    Foo Bar Baz
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Now suppose we want to change the *value* of the text itself (in this case, *"Foo Bar Baz"*) while keeping its `<tspan>` descendants. If we use `textContent`, `innerHTML` (modern browsers support `innerHTML` for SVG) etc that will replace everything, children included:

```js
document.querySelector("text").textContent = "New Foo";
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    Foo Bar Baz
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

One workaround is getting the first NodeList element of the child nodes, which is *normally* the text itself:

```js
document.querySelector("text").childNodes[0].textContent = "New Foo";
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    Foo Bar Baz
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

However, this workaround is quite hacky. *"Why?"*, you might ask... well, using an hardcoded index in a collection is hacky enough to me. Also, like I wrote above, the first element in the collection is *normally* the text itself, but I have no idea if this is implementation-dependent and, therefore, a new browser can simply change that order in the collection, implementing a different sequence.

Hence the *proper way* in my question's title: is there a property or any other method to specifically change the text content only in an SVG `<text>` element?

Comment: You must make a clearer statement of what you want to do to avoid the confusion that bring people in will to help you to post wrong answers. Improve your question'and you will get better answers. – SIMBIOSIS 7 mins ago    Delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is there a property or any other method to specifically change the text content only?"

No, probably not. In fact, I think it might be for the better that such a method doesn't exist. Say for example that your `<text>` node looked like this:

```
<text>
  Foo
  <tspan>Bar</tspan>
  Baz
</text>
```

And now we would call the unknown method to change the text into `Hello world`. What would the desired outcome be?

```
<text>
  Hello world
  <tspan>Bar</tspan>
</text>
```

```
<text>
  <tspan>Bar</tspan>
  Hello world
</text>
```

or even

```
<text>
  Hello
  <tspan>Bar</tspan>
  world
</text>
```

Looking at it like this, it becomes clear that the "text content" can't be seen as a special case that exists apart from the node tree: just like the `<tspan>` in your example, there can be multiple text nodes in any order and quantity. It's therefore hard to justify a special method that only changes text nodes, without introducing method to only change all the `<tspan>`, `<div>` and so on as well.

### Solutions

If you regard all the text nodes as some kind of typeless elements like this:

```
<text>
  <text>Foo</text>
  <tspan>Bar</tspan>
  <text>Baz</text>
</text>
```

there is little question about how you would approach targeting and changing your desired element. Options include:

- Grab it by index (like you already did). Judging from the fictional snippet above, it would be pretty safe to assume that `Foo` will indeed always be the first element. But just like with the `:first` selector in CSS, you might rather not want to depend so rigidly on a specific structure.
- A `class="text"` attribute would be very clear, but then you'd need to wrap your text in an actual element (which might be the best solution, but I'm following your specs here).
- Grab the first element that is of the right type, just like you would with any other element.

The snippet below would therefore be a perfectly valid way to alter the first text node in a list of children (written in a functional manner to keep it concise).

```js
Array.from(document.querySelector("text").childNodes)
  .find(e => e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
  .textContent = "New Foo";
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    Foo Bar Baz
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see it you have two options. 1) Building on your last example where you look for the text node. You know that there is *one* text node with content. You can test all the childNodes of `<text>` to see if it is a text node and then replace that node. 2) You turn the text node into a `<tspan>` element just like the other child elements. This will make no difference visually and at then same time it is easier to refer to the element and style it if needed. The "cost" for adding this element is minimal.

```js
document.querySelector("text > .first").textContent = "New Foo";
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    <tspan class="first">Foo Bar Baz</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort (hence my +1), but despite #1 being a good approach (that's what I do, by the way), that's not what I'm looking for... What I'm looking for in this question is a proper SVG spec for this, but I'm afraid there is none.

Comment: Thanks. If you see it like that we have the same issue in HTML -- or to be more precise in the underlying XML and SGML specs. I don't think that this is solvable in SVG in itself. To work around this in practice I'm always thinking so myself: "can I reach this content using a CSS selector?" -- and that is my second solution.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment should be attached to the question and I place it here by mistake

Answer (score 1):

You might use the `nodeType` [property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) in a loop. It is important to notice that other text nodes can be added by the parser, so you also have to choose which one you need. A simple implementation substitutes the first node with `nodeType===3`. Other implementations are possible, taking into account that other type 3 nodes will have simple texts like `\n`. This will substitute the first text (not `tspan`) node that has some letter:

```js
const r = document.querySelector("text");
let hasText = /\w/;
for (x = 0; x < r.childNodes.length; x++){
  if (r.childNodes[x].nodeType === 3 && hasText.test(r.childNodes[x].textContent)){
    r.childNodes[x].textContent = "New Foo";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
    Foo Bar Baz
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach from the others. Replace the [Element.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) nodes directly using [Element.replaceChildren()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren) (No compatible with IE):

```js
const textNode = document.querySelector('text');

function updateTextContent(node, text) {
  node.replaceChildren(text, ...node.children);
}

updateTextContent(textNode, 'New Foo');
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="30">
    Foo Bar Baz
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBar</tspan>
    <tspan x="30" dy="30">FooBaz</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

If you need support for IE, replace the textContent property value, and then use [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to add the children nodes:

```
function updateTextContent(node, text) {
  const children = [...node.children];
  node.textContent = "";
  node.append(text, ...children);
}
```